# SQL Server 2008 R2 : after manual record insert into column with unique key index constraint

Tags: sql-server, indexing, key, constraints, unique

I have an app that allows users to insert a record into a table with a column that has a unique key index constraint defined as

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [my_IDX2] 
    ON [dbo].[myTable] ([seq_no] ASC)
```

It works perfectly, but after an unrelated and successful manual record database insert into the same table using SSMS, subsequent records cannot be added through the app, here is the error message:

> Database error code:  2601
>
> Database error message:
>   SQLSTATE = 23000
>   Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.myTable' with unique index 'my_IDX2'.

It seems to me the fix is to increment the `my_IDX2` index to the last value I used (**+1**) during the manual insert but is that possible? How?

Comment: Are you using a `sequence` instead of `identity`?

Comment: It is neither. The [seq_no] is the name of the column and the values in it appear to be incremented by 1. When the a record is added through the app, it obviously gets then next increment. When I insert a record directly, I may be missing a call to the index to give me the next value. I need to somehow redefine the next value of my_IDX2 index but I'm not sure how to about doing it

Comment: Indexes do nit give values. I think you must be talking about a sequence.

Comment: Perhaps. Is it possible to adjust the sequence to use a certain value? My problem is not whether it is an identity or sequence.  The issue reallly is how to increment, adjust, reset to a different value or to reestablish a new next value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `sequence` and then manually inserting a sequential value, the `sequence` object doesn't know that. It is keeping track of the numbers it generates only. This is most helpful when you want a single source of unique numbers to use with more than one table.

An `identity`, on the other hand, keeps track of the values it has generated, but also accounts for other values manually inserted into the table.

Here is a quick comparison of how a `sequence` and `identity` react to inserted values they did not generate.

Test setup: http://rextester.com/VDDF36095

```
/* ------------- using sequence ----------- */
create sequence organisation_seq as bigint 
  start with 1 increment by 1;
create table organisation
(
  id bigint not null default next value for organisation_seq,
  customer_number varchar(50) unique
);

insert into organisation values
 (next value for organisation_seq, 'a')
,(200, 'b')
,(next value for organisation_seq, 'c');

select * from organisation;
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | customer_number |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | a               |
| 200 | b               |
|   2 | c               |
+-----+-----------------+
```

---

If you use `identity` instead:

```
/* ------------- using identity ----------- */
create table organisation_identity
(
  id bigint not null identity (1,1),
  customer_number varchar(50) unique
);

insert into organisation_identity values
('a');

/* ------------- identity_insert on ----------- */
set identity_insert organisation_identity on;
insert into organisation_identity (id, customer_number) values
(200, 'b');
set identity_insert organisation_identity off;
/* ------------- identity_insert off ----------- */

insert into organisation_identity values
('c');

select * from organisation_identity;
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | customer_number |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | a               |
| 200 | b               |
| 201 | c               |
+-----+-----------------+
```

---

A dirty workaround for either would be to use only positive integers for your `sequence` or `identity` and get the `min(id)-1` for manually inserted values.

Sequence Reference:

- [Sequence Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)
- [`create sequence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)
- [`next value for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx)
- [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx)
- [Simple Talk - Sql Server sequence basics - Joe Celko](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/)

Identity Reference:

- [`identity()` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)
- [`identity()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx)
- [`scope_identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)
- [`set identity_insert` - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved! I found a separate table in the app's database that manages all sequences, strange design but ok.  Once I found the specific record and adjusted the next value, the issue disappeared.  Thanks all for responding.